# my "remember me"-feature

Tags: php, mysql

Finally I have got this function to work. It does its job but it looks real messy, just wanna hear your thoughts and maybe theirs something I could improve?

Thanks alot!

Login

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."' AND password = '".md5($_POST['password'])."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_object($result);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        exit('Bad Login');
    }

    $_SESSION['id'] = mysql_result($result, 0, 'id');

    # The user wants to be remembered
    if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
        $key = md5(uniqid());
        setcookie('remember', $key, time()+900000);  /* expire in 10 days */
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET sessionkey = '$key' WHERE id = ".mysql_result($result, 0, 'id'));

    }
```

And on each page I check:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
header("Location: welcome.php");
}

elseif (isset($_COOKIE['remember'])) {

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE sessionkey = '$_COOKIE[remember]'");

if (mysql_num_rows($rs) == 1) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = 1;
header("Location: welcome.php");
}

}
```

Comment: There is always several ways to do things. Your approach is okay for a small non-demanding app. I'd probably use an OOP approach though and divide the concerns and roles into Authentication Service, Database Adapter and User Entity, etc. A lot more code though.

Answer (score 2):

Put the code that checks if the number of rows is zero before the `mysql_fetch_object($result)` statement. That way, you don't waste that extra CPU cycle if the user doesn't exist.

Change this (in both places):

```
mysql_result($result, 0, 'id');
```

to

```
$row->id;
```

Also, if your `id` column isn't sanitary (i.e.: the user has entered some data for it at some point), you're going to want to escape it in your `UPDATE` query.

Just a matter of preference on this one, but when I check URL parameters existance, I like to use `!empty()` instead of `isset`. The reason is that if the parameter is set but empty, it will still return false:

```
!empty($_POST['remember'])
```

Also on that note, be sure to sanitize `$_COOKIE['remember']`. Cookie values can be changed by the user.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE sessionkey = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE[remember]) . "'");
```

Lastly, it might be a good idea not to select `*` in your query, as this can bump you up against a performance wall later on in your app. Consider just selecting, say, the ID of the user:

```
mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users ...
```

Everything else looks pretty good!

Answer (score 0):

I'm no PHP expert, but there's probably an off-the-shelf solution for session management - I would suggest using it over rolling your own.

Comment: Session controlling, yes: The $_SESSION variable that Sven is already using. But session data is only stored for one browser session, where Sven wants the user to remain logged in even after the session has ended.

Comment: By session I mean the broader sense, i.e. user session, not browser session.

Comment: Ah okay. PHP has no built-in solution for user session management, afaik.

Comment: And no 3rd party/open source solution?

Comment: My web app uses roughly the same solution as the submitter's. Anyone have any recommendations for a standalone third party solution? (i.e. not something that's just a plugin for a framework, something you can just plug and play into any setup.)